# Oracle Reports splitting columns to extra rows in spreadsheet output

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oraclereports

I'm currently working with some oracle 10g reports that export the data to `.xls` format using `ENHANCEDSPREADSHEET` as the `DESFORMAT`.

The problem I am encountering is that data for some columns is being split onto extra rows. Originally I thought that it was just because the data had carriage returns/newline feeds. However I've added `REPLACE(REPLACE(location, CHR(10), ''), CHR(13), '')` to the query for the report. This removed a few of the lines that were displaying this duplication.

Though not certain I'm beginning to think that its caused by the columns having their vertical elasticity set to Expand. (This has been tried on variable and fixed as well.) With the vertical elasticity set to fixed the row duplication stops but the data is truncated on the start of the new line in the spreadsheet (I'm assuming its just a fixed value) and the variable option displayed the exact same row duplication as Expand.

Has anyone else ever encountered this problem? How did you fix it if you did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come across this before. I think it's something to do with how Reports lays out multiple-page reports. I fixed it by increasing the height of all the fields quite a bit, setting Vertical Elasticity to Expand, and Horizontal Elasticity to Fixed.[image]

Comment: Thanks I just tried this out on one of the reports and I cant find any extra rows. I'll add it to the rest now. Thank you very much.